# Python - What are lambdas for?

Tags: python, lambda

I understand what they do and how to use them, but I'm still somewhat confused as to why they're included in Python. What benefit is there in using them, over the normal function definition style?

The only real difference that I can think of is that you can create them inside an expression. For example, if myList was a list of ints and you wanted to add one to every element, you could use

```
list(map(lambda x: x+1, myList))
```

Whereas if you wanted to do that with function definitions, you'd have to define it elsewhere and then pass that variable.

However, I seriously doubt that this relatively minor convenience would justify their inclusion in the language, so I'm guessing there's something I'm missing. Or, perhaps, I'm underestimating the usefulness of being able to create functions inside lines like that.

So, that's basically my question - what are lambdas supposed to be used for? Why are they included?

Comment: It really is just that.

Comment: Worth a read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function.

Comment: A lambda is an anonymous function meaning you only need it temporarily. It is a bit of functional programming in Python.

Comment: You're not missing anything. I believe I read somewhere Guido actually wanted to nuke them for Python 3 based on your exact reasoning.

Comment: with a anonymous function, I don't have to give a name to it. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Lambda - why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/python-lambda-why)

Comment: For goodness sake, putting this on hold as "opinion-based" is silly:  while people can have opinions about whether they *like* lambda, the question was why they're in the language.  I explained that (I was there at the time), and gave a link to the blog post where Python's creator explained why they're in the language. That's not opinion, that's fact.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There isn't a deep answer to this.  A long time ago, someone contributed the code to implement `lambda`, and in a weak moment ;-) Guido (van Rossum) applied the patch.  That's all there is to it.

It *is* handy sometimes, although it's mostly over-used.  For example, in various GUI systems you often want to pass a simple callback function to be triggered when some element in the GUI is clicked.  `lambda`s are really nice for that.

FYI, here's the entry Guido made at the time, for Python release 1.0.0 (26 January 1994).  You can find this in a Python distribution's `Misc/HISTORY` file:

> There is a new keyword 'lambda'.  An expression of the form
>
> lambda parameters : expression
>
> yields an anonymous function.  This is really only syntactic sugar;
>   you can just as well define a local function using
>
> def some_temporary_name(parameters): return expression
>
> Lambda expressions are particularly useful in combination with map(),
>   filter() and reduce(), described below.  Thanks to Amrit Prem for
>   submitting this code (as well as map(), filter(), reduce() and
>   xrange())!

So blame Amrit Prem - LOL ;-)

**EDIT** And [click here](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2009/04/origins-of-pythons-functional-features.html) to read Guido's blog post on the subject.  It's curious that he didn't remember to look in `Misc/HISTORY`, forgot the name of the patch author, and that his memories are off by several years.  Good thing I'm still around to cover for him ;-)

Comment: [It's Tim!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) It's always kind of weird seeing you.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for pointing that out, no joke; considering he contributed to Python.

Comment: Oh! Oh! This got downvoted - that's hilarious ;-)

Comment: @TimPeters [This questioner](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30128187/1903116) wants to know why Python's `map` uses `None` as a fill-in. I am still searching and couldn't find why. Please take a look at at if you have time :-)