# Why does map work like izip_longest with fill=None?

Tags: python, dictionary, zip

When `map` has different-length inputs, a fill value of `None` is used for the missing inputs:

```
>>> x = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6]]
>>> map(lambda *x:x, *x)
[(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, None), (4, None)]
```

This is the same behavior as:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.izip_longest(*x))
[(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, None), (4, None)]
```

What's the reason `map` provides this behavior, and not the following?

```
>>> map(lambda *x:x, *x)
[(1, 5), (2, 6), (3,), (4,)]
```

…and is there an easy way to get the latter behavior either with some flavor of `zip` or `map`?

Comment: It is well [documented](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#map), and was removed(or say fixed) in Python 3 to make it equivalent to `itertools.imap`. Reason may be somewhere in old CPython source code or mailing list.

Comment: Consider: what should be the result on `[[1,2,3,4],[5,6],[7,8,9,10]]`, and would that differ from the result on `[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10]]`?

Comment: *What's the reason map provides this behavior, and not the following?* If a function takes two required positional arguments, you will get an error if you pass in only one. So IMO, it makes the most sense for None to be a replacement for a missing argument. Additionally check out @nneonneo's comment. Filling in None is the only way to assure that the elements of one and only one iterable is mapped to each positional argument.

Comment: Ultimately, there are a *lot* of functions in Python that use required positional arguments instead of the graceful *arg syntax. Having map provide behavior like in your last example would cause errors with these functions left and right. Only behavior from either zip/izip or izip_longest would make sense, and since having None as a positional argument is a common and valid use case, the behavior of izip_longest for the iterable arguments is arguably the most useful.

Comment: Also bear in mind, that while (1,) is legal, (,1) is not, what would the output be like if the first list was shorter?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Yes, I've seen the documentation, I was asking **why**.   @nneonneo: While your point is a good one, I absolutely disagree -- the behavior in 2.7 is **odd**, and to be consistent with most of python **should** probably truncate like `zip` does.  The fill with `None` at all is the surprising oddity.

Comment: @JosepValls: `(1,)` either way makes nearly as much sense as returning `(None, 1)`.  If you have a required number arguments, the latter makes sense -- but if you have a variable number of arguments, the former makes sense.  So, while I see your point (same as @nneonneo's), it doesn't answer what was the reasoning behind the choice.

Comment: Okay I dug deeper till the introduction of `map` in Python, which happened in `Release 1.0.0 (26 January 1994)`. Still digging to find out why it is using  `None` as a filler.

Comment: The moral of the story, of course, is that everything is better in Python 3.

Comment: Cringe.  Some things.  Not everything.  However, that's to be expected.  @Veedrac: Looking to start a flame war? (see: http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/272bao/python_34_slow_compared_to_27_whats_your_mileage/ among others)

Comment: @MikeMcKerns Pointing out that Python 3 has improved on Python 2 is about as "flame war"-y as saying that C++11 has improved on C++03. Pointing out that there are some cases where C++11 is slower than C++03 on one platform does little to change that.

Comment: @Veedrac: you said "everything is better" and not "has improved on".  See your comment above.  That's what I'm cringing about.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns That's seems like mere semantic pedanticism. The two statements express fundamentally the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this a design decision that the core devs opted for at the time they implemented `map`. There's no universally defined behavior for `map` when it is used with multiple iterables, quoting from [Map (higher-order function)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28higher-order_function%29#Language_comparison):

> Map with 2 or more lists encounters the issue of handling when the
>   lists are of different lengths. Various languages differ on this; some
>   raise an exception, some stop after the length of the shortest list
>   and ignore extra items on the other lists; some continue on to the
>   length of the longest list, and for the lists that have already ended,
>   pass some placeholder value to the function indicating no value.

So, Python core devs opted for `None` as placeholder for shorter iterables at the time [`map` was introduced](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/89e1e5d9ccbf/Python/bltinmodule.c#l472) to Python in 1993.

But in case of `itertools.imap` it short-circuits with the shortest iterable because its design is heavily inspired from languages like Standard ML, Haskell and APL. In Standard ML and Haskell `map` ends with shortest iterable(I am not sure about APL though).

Python 3 also removed the `map(None, ...)`(or we should say `itertools.imap`, Python 3's `map` is actually almost `itertools.imap`: [Move `map()` from `itertools` to `builtins`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/7adaab64eb72/Python/bltinmodule.c)) construct because it was present in Python 2 only because at the time `map` was added to Python there was no `zip()` function in Python.

From [Issue2186: `map` and `filter` shouldn't support `None` as first argument (in Py3k only)](http://bugs.python.org/issue2186#msg63007):

> I concur with Guido that we never would have created `map(None, ...)` if
>   `zip()` had existed.  The primary use case is obsolete.

---

To get the result you want I would suggest using `itertools.izip_longest` with a sentinel value(`object()`) rather than default `None`, `None` will break things if the iterables itself contain `None`:

```
from itertools import izip_longest


def solve(seq):
    sentinel = object()
    return [tuple(x for x in item if x is not sentinel) for item in 
            izip_longest(*seq, fillvalue=sentinel)]


print solve([[1,2,3,4],[5,6]])
# [(1, 5), (2, 6), (3,), (4,)]
```

Comment: Sounds good.  I'll take it that you are saying there's no easy way to get the truncated behavior off of some flavor of `zip` or `map`…

Comment: Oh, you found more appropriate references +1 :) I gave up after sometime and [asked Tim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20320585/python-what-are-lambdas-for/20320604#comment48368640_20320604) if he could help here :D

Answer (score 1):

Given that the first list is always longer and that there are only two lists, you would do something like this:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = ['a','b']
zip(x,y) + [(i,) for i in x[len(y):]]
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3,), (4,), (5,)]
```

Comment: Yup, and the final step would be to use `itertools.starmap`: `list(starmap(lambda *x: x, that_list))`

Comment: This adds a list to the `zip`, so no.  Besides, you can do this:  `map(lambda *x:tuple(i for i in x if i is not None), *x)`.  So, that's not what I was looking for.